# To dynamically add UIViews, or create a UITableView? ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm new to iOS development.  I'm currently working on an app that has dynamic content that is brought back from a web server, mapped into data models, and displayed to the user.

So far, I have created views to consume the models, and then add the views as sub views into a scroll view, calculating y coordinates for each so that they are added one under another.

This sequential adding of elements is "list like", and could be table cells in a table view. Thus far I've avoided this approach, because some of my views have varying heights, and I've read that performance on table views declines significantly when cells have dynamic row heights.

Do I risk performance adding sequential subviews into a scroll view? Is a tableview a better solution for what I'm describing?

Comment: Would you benefit from any standard table view behaviors like edit mode, row animations, scrolling to the top when the status bar is tapped, etc.?

Comment: unless you are doing something so radically different than a table view, I would use the UITableview and modify it to work with your design. You are essentially re-inventing the wheel by adding UIViews to a UIScrollView.

Comment: No, and tapping the status bar will already scroll my scroll view with subviews to the top. @Justin

Comment: @logixologist I'm okay with reinventing the wheel if it give me a little more control over what I'm trying to do. Does it hurt anything performance wise?

Comment: @JasonMcGraw how much data is going to be coming from the server that you are concerned about performance? If you are not dealing with a massive dataset... go for it. Wheels are invented every day :)

Comment: generally, if you need to show heaps of views in the scrollview, UITableView or UICollectionView are the solution, because of the memory problem.

Comment: @logixologist probably 10 to 15 views at a time - more coming as the user scrolls down, like in facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that table views performance can degrade with dynamic cell heights is merely because the system must call `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for every single cell in order to figure out the scroll bars properly. (Although this changes in iOS7 with the addition of the `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Those methods would allow you to provide quick and dirty estimate heights for non visible cells.)

In any case, it means scroll views will have the same performance problem: you will have to calculate the height of every single subview as you add it to the scroll view. (As you already mentioned.) In fact, table view's ability to load cells on demand would give you a lot of advantages performance wise over a stock scroll view.)

In general, you should pick the approach that makes the most sense for you. Scroll views are essentially a blank canvas where you "roll your own". Table views give you a lot of functionality "out of the box". If they are lists, I'd lean towards table views.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use a table view. You can use the heightForRowAtIndexPath to manage the row height.

Comment: I don't disagree, but you should try to support your suggestion with evidence.